# como obtener el id de mi registro?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mvc

Tengo un formulario con un campo tipo hidden donde quiero traer el id de mi registro de la siguiente tabla:

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered tbl2 table table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead align="center">
        <tr class="panel">
            <th>Documento</th>
            <th>Persona</th>
            <th>Tipo de capacitacion</th>
            <th>Fecha Inicial</th>
            <th>Fecha Final</th>
            <th>Lugar</th>
            <th>Tema</th>
            <th>Actividad</th>
            <th>Horas</th>
            <th>Evidencia</th>
            <th>Beneficiarios</th>
            <th>Editar</th>
            <th>Eliminar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->capacitaciones); $i++) { ?> <tr>
                <td><?php echo $this->capacitaciones[$i]['dlesDocumento'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->capacitaciones[$i]['dlesNombre'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->capacitaciones[$i]['tnesdNombre'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->capacitaciones[$i]['cnesFechainicial'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->capacitaciones[$i]['cnesFechafinal'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->capacitaciones[$i]['cnesLugar'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->capacitaciones[$i]['cnesTema'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->capacitaciones[$i]['cnesActividad'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->capacitaciones[$i]['cnesHoras'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->capacitaciones[$i]['cnesEvidencias'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->capacitaciones[$i]['cnesBeneficiariotras'] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <center> <button type="button" class=" btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-edit" id="btnEditcap" title="editar" value="<?php echo $this->capacitaciones[$i]['cnesId']; ?>"><span></span></button> </center>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"> <button type="button" class=" btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" id="btnEliminarcap" title="Eliminar" value="<?php echo $this->capacitaciones[$i]['cnesId']; ?>"><span></span></button> </td>
            </tr> <?php } ?> </tbody>
</table> Estoy trabajando en la accion actualizar , con mvc , a continuacion el modelo: public function EditCapacitacion($fechain,$fechafin,$lugar,$tema,$horas,$actividad,$evidencia,$beneficiarios){ $edit = $this->_db->exec(" UPDATE capacitaciones SET ' `cnesFechainicial`='" . $fechain . "', `cnesFechafinal`='" .$fechafin . "', `cnesLugar`='" .$lugar. "', `cnesTema`='" . $tema. "', `cnesActividad`='" . $actividad. "', `cnesHoras`='" . $horas. "', `cnesEvidencias`='" . $evidencia. "', `cnesBeneficiariotras`='" . $beneficiarios."'"); if($edit){ return 1; }else{ return 0; } } Este es mi formulario: <form id="formCapacitaciones" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo BASE_URL . 'heimdal/ndp/GuardarCapa'; ?>">
    <!-- id para capacitaciones--> <input type="text" name="idcapa" id="idcapa" value="<?php echo $id = $this->capacitaciones['cnesId'] ?>">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Persona<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
            <div class="col-md-6"> <select id="capFuncionario" class="form-control" name="capFuncionario">
                    <option disabled="disabled" value="" selected="">Seleccione...</option> <?php for ($j = 0; $j < count($this->Funcionario); $j++) : ?> <option value="<?php echo $this->Funcionario[$j]['dlesDocumento']; ?>"><?php echo $this->Funcionario[$j]['dlesNombre']; ?></option> <?php endfor; ?>
                </select> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Tipo de capacitacion<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
            <div class="col-md-6"> <select id="capTipocap" class="form-control" name="capTipocap">
                    <option disabled="disabled" value="" selected="">Seleccione...</option> <?php for ($x = 0; $x < count($this->tipocapa); $x++) : ?> <option value="<?php echo $this->tipocapa[$x]['tnesdId']; ?>"><?php echo $this->tipocapa[$x]['tnesdNombre']; ?></option> <?php endfor; ?>
                </select> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Fecha Inicial<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
            <div class="col-md-6"> <input class="form-control" type="date" name="capFechaini" id="capFechaini" value=""> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Fecha Final<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
            <div class="col-md-6"> <input class="form-control" type="date" name="capFechafin" id="capFechafin" value=""> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Lugar<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
            <div class="col-md-6"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="capLugar" id="capLugar" value=""> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 text-right"> Tema <sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
            <div class="col-md-6"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="capTema" id="capTema" value=""> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 text-right"> Actividad <sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
            <div class="col-md-6"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="capActividad" id="capActividad" value=""> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Horas<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
            <div class="col-md-6"> <input class="form-control" type="number" name="capHoras" id="capHoras" value=""> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Evidencia<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
            <div class="col-md-6"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="capEvidencia" id="capEvidencia" value=""> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Beneficiarios<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
            <div class="col-md-6"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="capBeneficiarios" id="capBeneficiarios" value=""> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group btn-saves">
        <div class="text-center"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGuardarcap">Guardar</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button> </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

mvc:hi jngmnm,b,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

modelo:

```
''i
```

public function EditCapacitacion($fechain,$fechafin,$lugar,$tema,$horas,$actividad,$evidencia,$beneficiarios){
      $edit = $this->_db->exec(" UPDATE capacitaciones SET
    '  `cnesFechainicial`='" . $fechain . "', `cnesFechafinal`='" .$fechafin . "', `cnesLugar`='" .$lugar. "', `cnesTema`='" .  $tema. "', `cnesActividad`='" . $actividad. "', `cnesHoras`='" . $horas. "', `cnesEvidencias`='" . $evidencia. "', `cnesBeneficiariotras`='" . $beneficiarios."'");
    if($edit){
       return 1;
    }else{
       return 0;
    }
   }'''

Comment: les agradesco si me ayudan a editar la pregunta , tuve problemas.

Comment: Añade tres comillas invertidas al principio y al final de tu código `\`\`\`codigo aqui\`\`\``